# Is an e-mail queue necessary in an e-mail-heavy web app?

Tags: email

In a couple of recent projects, I've written an e-mail queue as a database table that is checked every minute by a cronjob. The cron script waits a few seconds in between sends.

The reason I did this was because I read somewhere that it helps your e-mail not end up in the spam folder if it's not blasted out from the same server all at once. I don't remember where I read it.

What do you think? Should I just mail things immediately or is an e-mail queue a good idea?

What are some pros and cons to this approach?

EDIT: Added last paragraph.

Comment: Unless you're inundating a particular provider with email, nobody actually has enough of a global perspective to notice you're sending a lot of messages at once.  The best way you can avoid your email ending up in the spam bin is by a) not sending spam, b) implementing DKIM and SPF, and c) getting on a DNS whitelist like dnswl.org .

Comment: I think email queue is good but for different reasons. You will not be accused of trying to DoS the receiving server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over your SMTP server? If so, then there's no point in doing an email queue PHP-side. The SMTP server will already have queueing capabilities. If you're worried about blasting a particular receiving server, you can always turn on your SMTP server's throttling (if it has it), something along [these lines](https://serverfault.com/questions/56719/postfix-stagger-rate-limit-outbound-mail).